# SQLite Database not being created in android studio

Tags: android, sqlite

bit of a beginner in android and so far i have built a small task to send some information to a database.

In the main activity it gets the values and then tries to pass it along to the database using the bellow methords.

(in extends actvity)

```
private DBManager dbManager;
```

(on create)

```
dbManager = new DBManager(this);
dbManager.open();
```

(in on create after values are laid out)

```
dbManager.insert( id, cat, title, datec, datem, name, image, video);
```

it then passes the data along to the DBManager class

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.util.Log;

public class DBManager {
private DatabaseHelper dbHelper;

private Context context;

private SQLiteDatabase database;

public DBManager(Context c) {
    context = c;
}

public DBManager open() throws SQLException {
    dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
    database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;

}

public void close() {
    dbHelper.close();
}


public void insert(String id, String cat, String title, String datec, String datem, String name, String image, String video) {
    ContentValues contentValue = new ContentValues();
    contentValue.put(DatabaseHelper.TAG_TUTID, id);
    contentValue.put(DatabaseHelper.TAG_CATID, cat);
    contentValue.put(DatabaseHelper.TAG_TUTTITLE, title);
    contentValue.put(DatabaseHelper.TAG_NAME, name);
    contentValue.put(DatabaseHelper.TAG_DATEC, datec);
    contentValue.put(DatabaseHelper.TAG_DATEM, datem);
    contentValue.put(DatabaseHelper.TAG_IMAGE, image);
    contentValue.put(DatabaseHelper.TAG_VIDEO, video);
    database.insert(DatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME, null, contentValue);
    Log.d("testing insert: ", cat);
}

public Cursor fetch() {
    String[] columns = new String[] { DatabaseHelper._ID, DatabaseHelper.TAG_TUTID, DatabaseHelper.TAG_CATID, DatabaseHelper.TAG_TUTTITLE, DatabaseHelper.TAG_NAME, DatabaseHelper.TAG_DATEC, DatabaseHelper.TAG_DATEM, DatabaseHelper.TAG_IMAGE, DatabaseHelper.TAG_VIDEO };
    Cursor cursor = database.query(DatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor != null) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    return cursor;
}

public int update(long _id, String id, String cat, String title, String datec, String datem, String name, String image, String video) {
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(DatabaseHelper.TAG_TUTID, id);
    contentValues.put(DatabaseHelper.TAG_CATID, cat);
    contentValues.put(DatabaseHelper.TAG_TUTTITLE, title);
    contentValues.put(DatabaseHelper.TAG_NAME, name);
    contentValues.put(DatabaseHelper.TAG_DATEC, datec);
    contentValues.put(DatabaseHelper.TAG_DATEM, datem);
    contentValues.put(DatabaseHelper.TAG_IMAGE, image);
    contentValues.put(DatabaseHelper.TAG_VIDEO, video);
    Log.d("testing update: ", image);

    int i = database.update(DatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME, contentValues, DatabaseHelper._ID + " = " + _id, null);
    return i;
}

public void delete(long _id) {
    database.delete(DatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME, DatabaseHelper._ID + "=" + _id, null);
}

}
```

Which uses the bellow to create a database.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

// Table Name
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "TODOS";

// Table columns
public static final String _ID = "_id";
public static final String TAG_TUTID = "tutID";
public static final String TAG_CATID = "catID";
public static final String TAG_TUTTITLE = "tutTitle";
public static final String TAG_NAME = "tutText";
public static final String TAG_DATEC = "tutDateCreated";
public static final String TAG_DATEM = "tutDateModified";
public static final String TAG_IMAGE = "imageID";
public static final String TAG_VIDEO = "videoID";


// Database Information
static final String DB_NAME = "tuts.DB";

// database version
static final int DB_VERSION = 1;

// Creating table query
private static final String CREATE_TABLE = "create table " + TABLE_NAME + "(" + _ID
        + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + TAG_TUTID + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + TAG_CATID + " TEXT, " + TAG_TUTTITLE+ " TEXT, " + TAG_NAME+ " TEXT,  " + TAG_DATEC+ " TEXT, " + TAG_DATEM+ " TEXT,  " + TAG_IMAGE+ " TEXT, " + TAG_VIDEO+ " TEXT);";

public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
    Log.d("testing create: ", DB_NAME);}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);
    Log.d("testing delete: ", DB_NAME);
}
}
```

the log cat shows that the insert methrod is being run, but that is the only thing that logcats, the creation of the database itself doesnot, furthermore i cannot find a new database using device explorer.

Any advice on where my problem lies would be greatly appreciated. 
Thank you for your time.

Comment: The method wasn't called even the first time you launched your app?

Comment: Apologies this was the case of having to similar progects and then looking in the wrong database folder.